# How can I change XSLT to using dynamic XPath using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm using Asp.net to make a transformation in XML using XSLT by C# code as follows.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strXSLTFile = Server.MapPath("EmployeeXSLT.xslt");
        string strXMLFile = Server.MapPath("Employess.xml");

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strXMLFile);

        XslCompiledTransform objXSLTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        objXSLTransform.Load(strXSLTFile);
        StringBuilder htmlOutput = new StringBuilder();
        TextWriter htmlWriter = new StringWriter(htmlOutput);
        objXSLTransform.Transform(reader, null, htmlWriter);
        ltRss.Text = htmlOutput.ToString();
        reader.Close();
    }
```

and for full example with (Asp.net, XSLT and XML) follow this link 
[Doing XSLT Transformation in ASP.Net](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/336_Doing_XSLT_Transformation_in_ASPNet.aspx)

Now I need to change the Xpath value of the XSLT file. I conduct a search to find out how to do this. finally, I found tow concepts to affect the XSLT file. However, no examples provided on how to apply these concepts to change XSLT "match" or "for-each select" where I need to add a variable for changeable Xpath.

the first one: 
using so-called [Dynamic XPath Evaluation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate)

the second one: 
using so-called [XSLT Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-parameters)

I need to know how can I change the XSLT "match" using C# code to meet specific selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XPathNavigator to compile an xpath expression then go through the matching nodes in your c# code.

```cs
// Create and compile the XPathExpression
string _xPathExpression = "/Data/Client[Id = 123]";
XPathExpression exprXPathCompiled 
    = xmlDocInputNavigator.Compile(_xPathExpression);

// Load the Stylesheet
XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
XslCompiledTransform xsltTemplate = new XslCompiledTransform();
xsltTemplate.Load(_stylesheetFileName, settings, new XmlUrlResolver());

// Create an iterator to loop through the matching nodes
XPathNodeIterator iterator = xmlDocInputNavigator.Select(exprXPathCompiled);
StreamWriter fileOutput = null;

while (iterator.MoveNext())
{
    //...
```

[XPathNavigator docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator)

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you explained the problem you are trying to solve, rather than the method you want to use to solve it.

An XSLT stylesheet is an XML document, so you can always transform it using XSLT (with a so-called "meta-stylesheet").

With XSLT 3.0 (not available from Microsoft, but available to C# users via the Saxon library) you can parameterize a stylesheet using "shadow attributes", for example

```
<xsl:template _match="{$pattern}"/>
```

where $pattern is a stylesheet parameter declared as

```
<xsl:param name="pattern" static="yes"/>
```

so that a value can be supplied by the calling application.

You can also of course use conventional (run-time) parameters in a match pattern of the form

```
<xsl:template match="*[@id=$requestedId]"/>
```

XSLT 1.0 doesn't allow parameter references in match patterns, unfortunately. Some XSLT 1.0 processors don't enforce this restriction but I don't know if that's the case for the Microsoft processor.